# Removing Ubuntu from a dual-boot install

Tags: arch-linux

I am an Arch Linux user and I decided to try out Ubuntu just because, not really liking it.

Arch Linux was installed with a 3 partition setup (`/boot` `/swap` `/`) and then I installed Ubuntu. I gave Ubuntu 50GB and Arch has 100GB.

Now, Ubuntu has taken power of Grub and it's the default thing that gets run (undesirable currently).

How can I take Ubuntu off the hard drive and get the original Arch Linux setup? IIRC by default Arch Linux has like a... "(fallback initframs)" or something along those lines as an entry in Grub, aside from the main Arch and the memory tester.

Any help is appreciated. I have not tried anything yet because, how do you say, I think this is a one-try thing.

```
eduan@eduan-Vostro-1500:~$ sudo fdisk -l
[sudo] password for eduan: 

Disk /dev/sda: 160.0 GB, 160041885696 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 19457 cylinders, total 312581808 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00022bd0

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *          63      996029      497983+  83  Linux
/dev/sda2          996030     8996399     4000185   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda3         8996400   214846334   102924967+  83  Linux
/dev/sda4       214847486   312580095    48866305    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       214847488   312580095    48866304   83  Linux

eduan@eduan-Vostro-1500:~$ cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=45b7e030-d275-490a-9b3e-dd52012cbd24 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=b8d7f8f2-ecbb-4fe2-a820-96b3e23611ad none            swap    sw              0       0

eduan@eduan-Vostro-1500:~$ cat '/media/81939e82-c05b-43a3-a722-5278535b2400    /etc/fstab' 
# 
# /etc/fstab: static file system information
#
# <file system> <dir>   <type>  <options>   <dump>  <pass>
UUID=1c1faf65-0236-4ef2-9acd-2dac88f683ab /boot ext4 defaults 0 1
UUID=81939e82-c05b-43a3-a722-5278535b2400 / ext4 defaults 0 1
UUID=b8d7f8f2-ecbb-4fe2-a820-96b3e23611ad swap swap defaults 0 0

eduan@eduan-Vostro-1500:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda5        46G  4.3G   40G  10% /
udev            987M   12K  987M   1% /dev
tmpfs           399M  896K  398M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            996M  856K  995M   1% /run/shm
/dev/sda3        97G   22G   71G  24% /media/81939e82-c05b-43a3-a722-5278535b2400

$ sudo df -h
[sudo] password for eduan: 
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda3        97G   22G   70G  24% /
dev             996M     0  996M   0% /dev
run             999M  812K  998M   1% /run
tmpfs           999M  3.9M  995M   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           999M     0  999M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           999M  218M  782M  22% /tmp
/dev/sda1       463M   33M  403M   8% /boot
/dev/sda5        46G  4.1G   40G  10% /mnt/45b7e030-d275-490a-9b3e-dd52012cbd24
```

Comment: well your explanation is reallyyyy unclear about what is your current configuration, could you show us your partition table ? grub could be update ffrom arch so Arch boot first.

Comment: @Kiwy How do I go about showing you my partition table? I hope `fdisk -l` from Ubuntu suffices. The first three partitions are Arch Linux's.

Comment: you could add `cat /etc /fstab` on both ubuntu and arch, also `df -h` from both

Comment: @Kiwy added what I could. To be honest doing `df -h` from Arch is a bit of a pain right now so it's only from Ubuntu (have a problem where I have to reset modem every time a computer is rebooted, and the whole family is currently up). Hope that's enough for now.

Comment: The grub boot loader configuration is probably still on the arch install. Most distros will have a "rescue" mode where you can boot from disc and it will find the distro on your system and put you in a scaled down version of it. On RHEL you get this by typing `linux rescue` at the isolinux boot prompt. I'd do that and then just `grub-install` ArchLinux's bootloader back.

Comment: Do you just want to change the grub's default system or do you want to remove Ubuntu?

Comment: @terdon Remove Ubuntu completely and get it to how it was before I installed Ubuntu.

Comment: OK, can you still boot into arch?

Comment: @terdon Definitely. I just have to select it from Grub at boot.

Comment: @Kiwy I added all the info you asked for. Everything was run from Ubuntu except the last `df -h` which was run from Arch.

Answer (score 2):

With the information you put, it seems that:

```
#Arch linux
$ sudo df -h
[sudo] password for eduan: 
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
     /dev/sda3        97G   22G   70G  24% /

#Ubuntu
df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda5        46G  4.3G   40G  10% /
```

You should launch arch linux and [update the grub](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB) and restore the grub from arch.
then you can remove Ubuntu from `/dev/sda5` you could launch a live linux that contains gparted and remove the partition for example.

Comment: Hi Kiwy, thanks for your help, finally getting to this. With "update the grub and restore the grub" you mean run `grub-install` and `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` as described [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#Install_to_disk)?